# CRM Dynamics 2011 SDK Writing Too Much Audit History

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm doing an import into CRM Dynamics 2011 via the SDK of contacts from our AD.  The problem I'm having is that even if I only change a single field all of the fields get written to the Audit History.  This is making it very hard to see what has changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing a create? If so, I think all fields are audited.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to capture auditing during import? If not, it is advised by Microsoft to disable during import due to this known cause/effect. GL!

Answer (score 2):

As glosrob described, its probably because you are doing a create, this commits every field to the database.

You could temporarily disable auditing on those fields you are not interested in.

If you open up the individual fields in the solution there is an option for auditing.

See this [image](http://magnetism.co.nz/images/blog-images-8/Auditing_Blog_Post_4.png?sfvrsn=0).